# Batch Script path with space double quote does not work

Tags: batch-file, path, space, filepath, iso

I have this script for mounting iso files

```
@echo off

set fileiso=%~1
set Exedir="C:\Program Files\OSFMount"

cd /d %Exedir%
osfmount -a -t file -f "%fileiso%" -m #:
```

if the path is like this:(%fileiso%)
D:\Download\another path with some iso inside\Iso\any.iso
not work

any help please :D

Comment: can you try to make the question a little more clear? I have difficulties reading your last line: how do you try to call the script? (give the command) and what is the output (error) you get?

Comment: i use this bat script in the sendto menù, right click on a .iso files and i call this script. if the path of .iso is like D:\Download\another path with some iso inside\Iso\any.iso the script not work

Comment: 1) i have used quote  osfmount -a -t file -f "%fileiso%" -m #:            2) i tryed the batch script directly from a cmd window     i have used quote  osfmount -a -t file -f "D:\Download\another path with some iso inside\Iso\any.iso" -m #: and working, so its not releated OSFMount program                                                    3) thanks for tip :D                                                4) i replace cd /d "%Exedir%" with pushd "%Exedir%"                                      but the script not work well :(

Comment: Try to debug it when you use `Send To`. Add `echo %fileiso%&pause` after the frist SET command

Comment: When you tried your script from the command-line, did you put your file path in quotes? I wonder whether your first argument is actually turning out to be the entire file path.

Comment: If you have the permissions then please delete this question as it was not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
set "fileiso=%~1"
set Exedir="C:\Program Files\OSFMount"
pushd "%Exedir%"
osfmount -a -t file -f "%fileiso%" -m #:
popd
pause
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files\OSFMount
Creating device...
Created device 1: G: ->
D:\Old C Drive\Users\williamsonm\Downloads\clonezilla-live-20130314-quantal-i386.iso
Notifying applications...
Done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: ok thanks for help the problem seems to be the encoding of the file bat.

Comment: yes now the script it's working, i created a new file and i rewrited the code